# There seems to be a error here, but I don't see it. The query is working but the echos are not!

Tags: php, sql

This query works fine, but there seems to be an error in the definitions as the echos don't produce.

```
<?php
            $dbname = 'pdartist2';
            $table = 'artowrk';
            // query
            $result = mysql_query("select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder from artwork where SCID = $SCID") or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                $AID = $row['AID'];
                $ThumbFilePath = $row['ThumbFilePath'];
                $Title = $row['Title'];
                $DisplayOrder = $row['DisplayOrder'];
                echo "$AID";
                echo "$ThumbFilePath";
                echo "$Title";
                echo "$DisplayOrder";
            }
            mysql_free_result($result);
        ?>
```

Comment: Can you verify that you are returning a result and going into the `while` loop by commenting out everything in there and adding a `var_dump($row);`

Comment: Is $SCID set? Does this query returns anything? Is the connection properly opened? Just blank or any errors?

Comment: Your query is either failing or returning no values. Also, you're wide open to SQL injection attacks. Please see the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210487/there-seems-to-be-a-error-here-but-i-dont-see-it-the-query-is-working-but-the

Comment: i see no reason why this shouldn't work—apart from "artwork" being misspelled. the problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Possible typo alert: `$table = 'artowrk'`

Comment: var_dump($row) to check if anything is returning from the query.

Comment: @Polynomial not necessarily; but please, poster, make sure that `$SCID` is escaped with a function like `mysql_real_escape_string` before you query the database!

Comment: @toon81 - Please don't recommend `mysql_real_escape_string` over parameterised queries. It is not a catch-all for preventing SQL injection. In fact, `1 OR 1 = 1` will still inject properly even if he uses `mysql_real_escape_string` on this query.

Comment: +1 for your comment, I hadn't realized that. You learn something new every day! SQL injection vulnerabilities are unfortunately quite common on here. At the shop where I work, parametrized queries are, for some reason, not used. I wish it were different! *(edit: minor fix in punctuation)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) does not return associative array, the returned array is a numeric indexed array. so you have to access it using numeric index like the below

```
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
```

If you want the array to be an associative array, you may try [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

and instead echo use [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) it will make sure you get output even for Boolean false which is ignored by echo or print_r

Comment: Thanks, I see that the array is the answer.