# Why does my code output each image 8 times?

Tags: php, mysql

[I have fixed my earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210487/there-seems-to-be-a-error-here-but-i-dont-see-it-the-query-is-working-but-the), but now the loop produces 8 or more images for each. In one gallery I have one a single image but get it eight times, not ten, not three, what's with the eight loops?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    $AID = $row['AID'];
    $ThumbFilePath = $row['ThumbFilePath'];
    $Title = $row['Title'];
    $DisplayOrder = $row['DisplayOrder'];
    foreach($row as $cell)
    {
        echo "<div id='clear'></div>";
        echo "<div id='thumb_container'>";
        echo "<a href='gallery_detail.php?AID=$AID'><img src='http://markdinwiddie.com/PHP2012/$ThumbFilePath' title='Enlarge' alt='Enlarge' border='0'></a>";
        echo "<div id='name_spacer'></div>";
        echo "<div id='thumbdesc'>";
        echo "$Title";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }                           
}
```

Comment: are you just running through the rows, or are you trying to make a specific width grid, like 3 images on every row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a nested loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_arry($result)){ //once for each row in the database
  foreach($row as $cell){ //once for each field in the table
  ...
  }
}
```

I'm guessing your table has 8 fields. Remove the `foreach{}`.

Comment: Thanks Fredley! I was using the foreach for something else and over looked that.

Answer (score 0):

8 columns selected in $result
so $row is an array consist of 8 element.

foreach($row as $cell)

foreach will loop 8 times.